# Marking grid points within a small circle on a sphere

Tags: algorithms, graphics

I have a [small circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere) (on a sphere) with given center and radius and I want to mark grid points which are within the small circle.

The grid itself is discretised in evenly spaced longitude and latitude degrees in a geographical map.

My simple algorithm that I implemented to solve this goes from the center of the small circle in small steps to the outer rim of the small circle and marks all points in the way. This is repeated for all azimuth angles from 0 to 360°.

The algorithm above is not only tremenduous slow, but also requires the right incrementation angles to not loose points and to not even being more slower.

Any idea for a good algorithm?

I am aware that my question goes in direction of flood fill algorithm, but I thought sometime about it, and it seems that for me it hasn't big advantages.

Comment: See [fast algorithm for drawing filled circles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201200/fast-algorithm-for-drawing-filled-circles)

Comment: Unfortunately a small circle "projected" on an equirectangular grid is never a circle and can have a lot of dissimilar shapes, depending on the location of the center of the small circle. E.g. if the small circle center is at a pole - the easiest case - then the small circle rim is just a straight line on a constant latitude. The same circle with the center at the equator is a slightly distorted ellipse, ... worse if it is located at the "sides" of your grid, then you may have two "half" ellipse at both sides.

Comment: See [calculating distance between two points, using latitude longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3694380/1493294)

Comment: Strange answer, sorry... These are my first posts here. Do we earn reputation by just the number of answers?

Comment: No, We earn reputation from well received questions and answers.  You could ask and answer many times and receive no rep.  Problems that people find difficult to relate to don't generate much reputation.  But you never really know what people are going to like.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You talk about a circle, then about the projection of a circle and ellipses in the comments. I think you are missing a lot of explanation. A picture says than a thousand words. If you could explain more clearly what input you have and what result you are expecting, you are more likely to get answers.

Comment: Sorry, that I was unclear for you. I am not speaking of a circle in a cartesian system. I am speaking of a **small** circle. A small circle is explained here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere). The grid that I am speaking of is an equirectangular grid, evenly spaced in degrees, which corresponds to longitude and latitude in a geographical map.

Comment: (continues)... If you draw this equirectangular grid in a cartesian plane (latitude vs longitude) and you draw the small circle in it, the shape of small circle varies from straight line to ellipse, depending on where the small circle center is located

Comment: @Domenico: so you are talking about a circle and grid on a **sphere** (which you did not clearly mention in your question, from what you wrote it could be just a planar map).

Comment: @Doc Brown: You are right, a small circle on a sphere, and a grid with evenly spaced grid points for latitude and longitude. So, if you look on a sphere you see the small circle (as a circle) but the grid points are not equally distributed in it ... If you project the problem on a planar map, then the grid is rectangular but the small circle is not a circle anymore ... sorry that I cannot explain it better

Comment: Prepending an adjective for size didn't explain the characteristic property of those circles very well to me. That's like describing the pyramids in Egypt as "***big** houses*". That wouldn't really tell the whole story, would it? Picking significant properties improves explanations. (like @Doc Brown's comment did) That being said, it's still unclear to me what your actual goal is. You talk about problems introduced by the projection in a comment, but you never explain which one you are using. And there are [quite a few out there](http://xkcd.com/977/) **Tell us everything!**

Comment: @null: when talking about circles on a *sphere*, the terms "small circle" and "great circle" have a special meaning, so for me this was just the piece of context that was missing. Moreover, this is a red herring, the question (and my answer) are valid also for great circles.

Comment: do you mean : i want to plot a circle (on the globe) on a flat map?

Comment: @DocBrown I did not understand why your answer is not correct.  Seems perfectly fine to me.  I do not see why it is a problem that "the range of longitude which must be covered is 360 degrees".  Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the basis of KISS let's stick to a sphere. Let the centre of the circle have latitude `φ` and longitude `θ`. Convert the radius of the circle to an angle `ψ = r / R`. Since lines of constant longitude are great circles (well, half-circles, because the longitude changes at the poles), the latitudes covered by the circle are `φ - ψ` to `φ + ψ`, limited to not go below -90 degrees or above +90 degrees.

Quantise the latitudes to your grid, and then for a given quantised latitude `λ` we need to get the range of longitudes. Obviously it's symmetric around `θ` (provided we're careful with how we talk about longitudes near ±180 degrees). In fact, the points which lie on the circumference of the small circle are `(λ, μ)` where

```
cos φ cos λ cos (θ - μ) + sin φ sin λ = cos ψ
```

Solve for `μ`. If you can't, it's because the entire line of latitude is inside the circle, which can happen near the poles.

If you want to optimise, you could use Taylor approximations for sin and cos to get values which can be quickly updated, and only use trig when the accumulated error is such that there's more than one candidate grid point.

Comment: Sounds great in theory! And if it works it saves a lot CPU time as my new strategy would then be:  - Compute the two longitudes belonging to a given small circle latitude,  - Compute grid index of both longitudes,  - and now this is the clou, mark all grid points within the two indexes found.  This solution requires only a single for-loop instead of a double proposed by "Doc Brown".  But what I do not understand from the given equation is that (sorry but I don't know yet how to write formulas and greek symbols) why _phi_ and _lamda_ have a _sin_ which lead to DBZ at equator.

Comment: I apologise: I didn't read the linked question and answer carefully enough, or I would have realised that they were using polar angle. Now corrected.

Comment: I am a newbie here and I have read that I have not to answer "thanks" or something like that, but I cannot without :-)! Your solution works perfect for me. I started basically with an error-prone n-square-algorithm and what you propsed is an exact (in my case) n-linear-agorithm. The speed increase is uncomparable and I even did not implement the (Peter-)Taylor :-) approximation ... ... ... Thanks!